# Why breakpoint() doesn't prompt idempotent location in for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, breakpoints, pdb

I have a very simple test file `breakpoint_test.py`

```
for i in range(3):                       #1
    breakpoint()                         #2
    print(f"first print in loop {i}")    #3
    breakpoint()                         #4
    print(f"second print in loop {i}")   #5
```

Here is output when I run it and keep press `c` to *continue*.

```
(py3) nakita@machine:~/tmp $ python breakpoint_test.py 
> /Users/nakita/tmp/breakpoint_test.py(3)<module>()
-> print(f"first print in loop {i}")                    <---------------looks good here!
(Pdb) c
first print in loop 0
> /Users/nakita/tmp/breakpoint_test.py(5)<module>()
-> print(f"second print in loop {i}")
(Pdb) c
second print in loop 0


> /Users/nakita/tmp/breakpoint_test.py(2)<module>()
-> breakpoint()                                         <---------------weird here!
(Pdb) c
first print in loop 1
> /Users/nakita/tmp/breakpoint_test.py(5)<module>()
-> print(f"second print in circle {i}")
(Pdb) c
second print in loop 1


> /Users/nakita/tmp/breakpoint_test.py(2)<module>()
-> breakpoint()
(Pdb) c
first print in loop 2
> /Users/nakita/tmp/breakpoint_test.py(5)<module>()
-> print(f"second print in circle {i}")
(Pdb) c
second print in loop 2
```

I expect `breakpoint()` will prompt the line which will be executed right after `breakpoint()`. This is true when code enters `for` loop first time. But when iterating in second loop, first breakpoint() prompts `breakpoint()` line itself instead of `-> print(f"first print in loop {i}")`. However, second `breakpoint()` in loop body works as I expect. Looks the behavior is first `breakpoint()` in for loop body will be sacrificed. Anyone know why?

I tested it on python 3.7.3 and 3.8.0.
I have read [PEP 553 -- Built-in breakpoint()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0553/#impl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is trying to start debugging on the start of the next line, but its "next line" detection is a bit wonky.

---

By default, `breakpoint` calls `pdb.set_trace`, which sets a [*trace function*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) that will execute on the next trace event. The next trace event in this case is a `'line'` event, triggered when Python thinks execution has entered a new line.

On the first execution of the first `breakpoint` in the loop, and on all executions of the second `breakpoint`, the next `'line'` event triggers on the first opcode of the next line. However, on second and later executions of the first `breakpoint`, something different happens.

Python determines that a new source line has started by checking whether the current bytecode instruction index corresponds to either the first instruction of a line, or an instruction at an index prior to the last instruction executed. You can see that in [`maybe_call_line_trace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) in `Python/ceval.c`.

Python only updates `instr_prev`, the variable used to determine the last instruction executed, when tracing is active. When you hit `c` to continue execution, the trace function is deactivated. (It would remain active if you had set any breakpoints with the PDB `break` command, since the trace function needs to handle those, but `breakpoint()` calls don't go through that mechanism.)

On the "non-weird" breakpoints, Python triggers the next line event on the first opcode of the next line, under the "first instruction of a line" condition.

On the "weird" breakpoints, `instr_prev` still has the value from the last time you hit `c`, because tracing was disabled at that point. That value is for a later line than the current line, so Python triggers the next line event on the next opcode of the `breakpoint()` line, under the "instruction at an index prior to the last instruction executed" condition. (The next opcode of the `breakpoint()` line is a `POP_TOP` to clean up `breakpoint`'s return value.) If Python had been keeping better track of the last instruction executed, it wouldn't have triggered that event.

Comment: Thanks, this answer bring me lots of new things.